# Canvas and Dialogue structure in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game and the player can run past a sign GameObject and if they are close enough to it, it will create a dialogue.

Now my issue here is, would it be a better idea structurally to have a prefab where each sign GameObject has a canvas (World Space?) as a child in which the dialogue that is created would then be placed as a child of the canvas GameObject?

or

Have 1 World Canvas in which I place all my sign GameObjects in as a child and just have the dialogue that is created be just a child of my sign GameObject?

Currently I am using the latter but I was wanting to pick a few brains and see if what I am doing is even the easiest way of handling random dialogue that you may come across.  This can be used for many things as well, such as walking up to a NPC and trying to talk to it.  The reason why I ask this is because since I am using the latter my hierarchy gets tossed around a bit since I have it pretty organized in each scene but now I find myself just moving certain GameObjects under this World Space Canvas GameObject and maybe it is just my non-expertise of this but it just seems not right and that I am doing something wrong and there is a "proper" way of handling something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of making things simple and have a lot of objects or more complex and minimize.

If you don't have already thousands of game objects, then I would recommend the UI for each object. It makes things more simple. Consider it with a real example, do you think it is better than everyone gets his own sign to be used when needed or should you only bring one sign and you pass it around when someone needs. Also, will there be any time when two signs could be shown at once?

All in all, I would add a sign to the prefab and everyone gets his own.